# How to determine the resonant peak magnitude of the closed loop via the Nichols chart?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, linear-control

I have been studying the control theory and I have recently found the [Nichols chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichols_plot) theme.
Among others this chart is useful for determining the resonant-peak magnitude of the closed loop based on the open loop frequency response. In [my text book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1292274522) there is written on page 446 that the resonant-peak magnitude can be determined as the magnitude of the highest closed-loop contour which is tangent to the curve forming the open loop frequency response. I have been trying to prove validity of this statement for some time but without success. Can anybody help with proving this statement?